# pillow rendering image in django

Tags: python, django

**Is any thing wrong with this program?**

```
@property
def imageURL(self):
try:
    url = self.image.url
except:
    url = ''
return url
```

**I used it but django does not render the images uploaded from the admin page**
**Please anyone with idea on how to fix this issue?**

Comment: and what do you have in `url` before `return url` ? And what url do you get in HTML ? Do you run in debug mode ? maybe you should remove `try/except` to see what error you get? OR at least you shodul use `except Exception as e: print(e)` to see that it can't get url. You should make some debug in your code - use at least `print()` to see what you have in varaible, what errors you get, and which part of code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [add django static and media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) URLS in urls.py *(only for DEBUG=True)*
Next use `src="{{ image_model.image.url }}"` in image field

Comment: Okay 
I'll do that